# link not working on android

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a site that generates a background image that stretches and scrolls with the browser via jquery. The idea is for when the page loads the user just clicks anywhere on the image and it takes them into the site.

I have an `<a>` tags around the body but there are a few issues:

*no prompting that it's a link by mouse on most browsers

*works on iPhone but won't even link at all on android.

What is the best, most cross-browser/mobile efficient way to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>THE BROADHURST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/css/thebroadhurst.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/css/jquery.vegas.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
      $.vegas({
        src:'/styles/images/bh_rotate/bhR_<?php echo rand(1,31); ?>.png'
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<a href="/home.php">
<body>
    <div class="structure_main clearfix">
    </div>
</body>
</a>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a first... Never seen anybody try and put the entire body within  an anchor before! As said in the answer, this is *badly* invalid HTML

Comment: I realize that now. However I've tried all three suggestions on this page and it's still not linking on droid.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this site is just meant for calling people out on their mistakes. If you wanna call me out and make a suggestion I understand that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "best" way of doing this is, but perhaps you can redirect the user with JavaScript when they click the body instead of making the whole body a link. Something along the lines of:

```
<body onclick="window.location = 'somewhere over the rainbow'">
```

... or attach it to the event later on:

```
​$(function() {
    $('body').click(function() {
        window.location = 'somewhere over the rainbow';
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This breaks web semantics, but at least your markup will be valid. If you want to have the `<a>` cursor when hovering over the body, just add the following CSS:

```
body { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: It works on a computer but now I can't enter the site at all on my iPhone, so I assume its the same for android until I can check.

Comment: @LightningWrist that's strange, I don't believe the code I suggested should cause loading the page to fail. Have any other changes been made to the site? Perhaps your iPhone does not have access to the network the site is on?

Comment: Not sure, however I took @Huangism's approach and wrapped a tags around all of the content inside the body. It's working on my iPhone but I'm waiting to hear back from client if it works on Droid. Pretty sure it doesn't as I'm pretty sure I have tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

That my friend is invalid HTML so I am not surprised it is not working

Closest thing I can think of is block link where you put the anchor after the body tag and end it before the closing body tag, but that just seems a bit... extreme